# How can I change column length using HQL query?

Tags: sql, schema, hql, bulk

I tried `session.createSQLQuery("ALTER TABLE People MODIFY address VARCHAR(1000);").executeUpdate();`

but this throws `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query`

After a lot of googling, the recommendation is to use HQL instead of SQL query to do bulk updates. Not sure how to use HQL to accomplish this. There seems to be no decent HQL documentation for updating column length in a table.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: no help, looks like it is not possible to alter the column, so I added a new column and manually copy over the data to new column at  start-up. New code uses new column and old one exists but unused. This solved my problem. Still curious to know if someone has a solution to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run this native SQL query via `session.connection()`.

See section **[16.2.2.1. Rules/limitations for using stored procedures](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query)** of [Chapter 16. Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html), it's near your *ALTER* query.

All the rest depends on your database vendor. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way. Looks like a limitation. I added a new field and copied over data from old field at start-up!